# Getting an error 413 Request Entity Too Large while using a plugin Croppic

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, croppic

I am using a jquery plugin `CROPPIC` to my web application to crop and compress the pictures before uploading them to database.
While I am using it I am able to crop and upload the picture size below 1MB but size above 1MB gives me an error in the console panel which is `413 Request Entity Too Large`.
Form more information I am working in PHP language. When I searched about the issue I came across various solutions like put some of the codes to my **php.ini** file.

> max_input_time = 24000
>   max_execution_time = 24000
>   upload_max_filesize = 12000M
>   post_max_size = 24000M
>   memory_limit = 120000M
>   client_max_body_size 24000M
>   max_file_uploads = 20
>   php_value
>   post_max_size 104857600

But all of these things are not working. If you like you can have a look to my project at http://www.bookiiee.com/ad_post.php and can ask more. Please help me out of this. I am working on the same issue for more than 2 days.

Comment: what are you using? apache? nginx?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. I am using apache.

Comment: @NikhilSindhu seems you have missed some `=` signs there. Don't know if that was a typo when you were posting question here.

Comment: Putting = is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the [`LimitRequestBody`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) directive. Example:

```
LimitRequestBody 0
```

Comment: Okay. Let me try out this.

Comment: Sorry, But still the issue is same.

Comment: have you restarted apache?

Comment: No, but how to do that.